# How can I get MIDL to search additional include directories for qualified paths

Tags: relative-path, include-path, midl

**Update:** Just over six months after opening a support call to Microsoft it has been rejected, they claim it is not a bug (since the documentation doesn't explicitly say that the behaviour seen isn't the correct one). They rejected the [DCR](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Design-Change-Request-%28DCR%29.html) saying that since they haven't heard any complaints in the last 10 years this is obviously not a common use case.

This is a call to arms, if you have run into the same issue, please open a support call with Microsoft so they understand that it should be fixed. I **know** that at least *someone* has run into the same problem becasue I found this comment in [Chrome's source code](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/gears/SConscript.browser):

> `#` Building .idl files.
> `#` This is a total mess.  MIDL needs to be run from $OPEN_DIR because it's too
> `#` stupid to apply its include paths to a relative path like "ui/ie/bla.idl"
> `#` (it only looks in the current dir).  So we have to jump through hoops to fix
> `#` up our relative include paths and output files.

---

**Original question:**

I have the following file structure:

- `C:\first\Foo.idl`
- `C:\second\Bar.idl`

Where `Bar.idl` contains the following line:

```
import "first/Foo.idl";
```

How can I get **midl** to compile `Bar.idl` when compiling from `C:\second`?

If I imported `Foo.idl` directly (without specifying `first/`) then specifying `first` as an additional include directory would be enough (`midl /I c:\first Bar.idl`) and it would find `Foo.idl`

Alternately if I compiled from `C:\` (`midl second\Bar.idl`) that would be OK too.

The problem is that when compiling from within `C:\second` with the command line `midl /I C:\ Bar.idl`, I get the following compilation error:

> c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'first\Foo.idl': No such file or directory

It looks like **midl** is willing to search relative paths only if they are relative to the current directory and not to one of the specified additional include directories and uses the additional include directories only for unqualified file names, this behaviour is specific to the `import` keyword, when using `include` the results are as expected.

I would like to be able to add two different additional include directories so that if I have the file on my local machine **midl** will take that version, otherwise it will take the file from the server (so `chdir`ing to the root folder is not an option).

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue since you last updated it?

Comment: @HenryMerriam nope, I contacted Microsoft support and they said they belive this is not a bug since it doesn't go explicitly against the doucumentation. Since they haven't heard this request before they feel it's not important enough to change the current behaviour :(

Answer (score 4):

Its the end of 2020 and MIDL 3.0 is out. However, the problem described by the OP still persists. But if you're using Visual Studio there is a straight forward way to deal with that issue.

If you're adding an .idl file to a project the following MSBuild code gets generated in the project file to which the .idl file is added:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Midl Include="Folder1\YourCustomFile.idl" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you add a second file in another folder and reference the first one this will generate another entry:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Midl Include="Folder1\YourCustomFile.idl" />
  <Midl Include="Folder2\YourSecondCustomFile.idl" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The problem is that if you compile that code the MIDL compiler will not be aware of any additional include directories. Hence, if you add

```c
#include "YourCustomFile.idl"
```

at the beginning of `YourSecondCustomFile.idl` the MIDL compiler will not search `Folder1` for any .idl files to be included and compilation will fail.

However, by adding `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` MSBuild item metadata you can influence which folders are passed to the MIDL compiler as additional include directories.

So, to instruct the MIDL compiler to search `Folder1` for include files when compiling  `YourSecondCustomFile.idl` modify the MSBuild code as follows:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Midl Include="Folder1\YourCustomFile.idl" />
  <Midl Include="Folder2\YourSecondCustomFile.idl">
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(ProjectDir);$(ProjectDir)Folder1</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
  </Midl>
</ItemGroup>
```

`ProjectDir` is an MSBuild property that points to the directory containing the current project (at least in C++ projects it does). The `;` is used to separate different directories. Each of those directories will be passed to the MIDL compiler as a separate directory to search for include files.

This should resolve the compilation problem. I don't think the `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` item metadata can be added using Visual Studio's user interface so you should edit the Visual Studio project directly in a text editor.

Note that the item metadata is valid *per item*, i.e. for each individual MIDL file. So, you have to add `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` to every MIDL file that references other MIDL file.

If you need the same content in multiple `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` you could define a property somewhere else in the project file like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <AdditionalMidlIncludeDirectories>$(ProjectDir);$(ProjectDir)Folder1;$(ProjectDir)Folder2</AdditionalMidlIncludeDirectories>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And then you use that property everwhere. You could add the same `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` statement to every single MIDL which would ensure that the same include directories would be used for every MIDL compiler call:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Midl Include="Folder1\YourCustomFile.idl">
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(AdditionalMidlIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
  </Midl>
  <Midl Include="Folder2\YourSecondCustomFile.idl">
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(AdditionalMidlIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
  </Midl>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comment below the code can be further simplified by applying MSBuild's [ItemDefinitionGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/itemdefinitiongroup-element-msbuild). An `ItemDefinitionGroup` is used to add metadata to MSBuild items which means that the `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` metadata can be automatically added to each and every `Midl` element. The `ItemDefinitionGroup` is defined as follows:

```xml
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Midl>
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      $(ProjectDir);
      $(ProjectDir)Folder1;
      $(ProjectDir)Folder2
    </AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
  </Midl>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

This simplifies the `Midl` `ItemGroup` as follows:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Midl Include="Folder1\YourCustomFile.idl" />
  <Midl Include="Folder2\YourSecondCustomFile.idl" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You can probably use `<ItemDefinitionGroup>` to set a default `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` value for all `Midl` items in the project, that way you don't need to specify it for every item individually.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was unaware of MSBuild's `ItemDefinitionGroup` element. Your proposal does work indeed and I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As you note, while this is dumb, Microsoft Support have confirmed this is not a bug. The following are possible workarounds.

### 1. Use the /I switch. A lot.

Use the `/I` switch to specify both `c:\first` and `c:\second`, and specify `import "Foo.idl"` instead of a relative path.

If the command line becomes too long specify a response file.

### 2. Use symbolic links

Use symbolic links or junctions to the include directories to reference them all into a single hierarchy under a known directory. Then you can use paths relative to that directory.

A pre-build step might be used to maintain the symbolic links.

MKLINK.exe can create junctions or symbolic links.

### 3. Use an additional build step

Create an additional build step which copies the required files to known locations, then inport them from there.

Comment: The real life situation has a bit more than `first` and `second`, in fact I believe that if I add all the possible directories I would exceed the maximal command line length.

Comment: @Motti, That is what response files are for.

Comment: That may work but it's far from maintainable for a large project. Much better if Microsoft supported sane semantics for `/I`.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a call to arms...

12 years, 6 months later, I'm here with my pitchfork, ready to go.

In the meantime, for an easier fix, you can go to Project Properties -> MIDL -> General -> Additional Include Directories. Setting that to "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\YourSubFolder" works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for coming! please place your pitchfork in the corner and once we reach a quorum of five (estimated circa 2081) we'll storm Microsoft's offices.